# Confusion matrix output error

Tags: r

I tried to build a predictive model in R using decision tree through this code:

```
library(rpart)
library(caret)

DataYesNo<-read.csv('DataYesNo.csv',header=T)

worktrain<- sample(1:50,40)
worktest <- setdiff(1:50,worktrain)

M <- ncol(DataYesNo)
input  <- names(DataYesNo)[1:(M-1)]                                   
target <- "ICUtransfer"                         

tree<- rpart(ICUtransfer~Temperature+RespiratoryRate+HeartRate+SystolicBP+OxygenSaturations,
                data=DataYesNo[worktrain, c(input,target)],
                method="class",
                parms=list(split="information"),
                control=rpart.control(usesurrogate=0, maxsurrogate=0))

fitted <- predict(tree, DataYesNo[worktest, c(input,target)])

cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(fitted, worktest$ICUtransfer)
print(cmatrix)

tree                
plot(tree)
text(tree)
```

I got error at :  cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(fitted, worktest$ICUtransfer)
"$ operator is invalid for atomic vectors "
please help me to solve this?
Regards,

```
DataYesNo[worktest,]
   Temperature RespiratoryRate HeartRate SystolicBP OxygenSaturations ICUtransfer
11        36.3              26        65        140                97          no
15        37.3              20        80        129                99          no
21        36.9              20        72        154                95          no
26        36.0              28        56        199                97          no
30        36.9              20        72        150                96          no
34        36.6              16        97        118                95         yes
36        36.0              20        77        145                97         yes
38        36.0              20        77        145                97         yes
43        36.3              28        98        116                95         yes
47        36.0              20        77        145                97         yes
```

I tried this line:

```
cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(fitted, DataYesNo[worktest,]$ICUtransfer)
```

but I got this error: Error in confusionMatrix.default(fitted, DataYesNo[worktest, ]$ICUtransfer) : 
  the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels

please anyone can help me?

Comment: Please post full error log/stacktrace.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting that error because `worktest` doesn't have any factor called `ICUtransfer`. `worktest` is just a numeric vector of indices, and thus has no factors. You want the subset of your data corresponding to the `worktest` indices.

It's impossible to know what exactly needs to be done, because I can't see into the data structures you're using.

Instead of `worktest$ICUtransfer` try using `DataYesNo[worktest, c(input,target)]`.

Comment: I tired your post then I got this error: Error in sort.list(y) : 'x' must be atomic for 'sort.list'
Have you called 'sort' on a list?

Comment: Well, since I don't know much about your problem domain, I can't give you much more specific information. Try `DataYesNo[worktest]`. What does DataYesNo look like?

Comment: I tried: cmatrix <- confusionMatrix(fitted, DataYesNo[worktest]$ICUtransfer)  then gave me : Error in `[.data.frame`(DataYesNo, worktest) : undefined columns selected

Comment: again: Error in confusionMatrix.default(fitted, DataYesNo[worktest, ]$ICUtransfer) : 
  the data and reference factors must have the same number of levels

Comment: Ok, now you've properly indexed into the matrix, but something else is wrong. Please edit your question, and add the values of the arguments to confusionMartix.